# Python | Nested loops | Sum of Sublists

Tags: python, sum, nested-loops

My goal with this is to generate the sum of each sublist separately using nested loops

This is my list called sales_data

```
sales_data = [[12, 17, 22], [2, 10, 3], [5, 12, 13]]
```

The sublist can be represented by any variable but for the purpose of this exercise, we will call it scoops_sold, which I have set to 0

```
scoops_sold = 0
```

So far I am able to run the nested loop as follows

```
sales_data = [[12, 17, 22], [2, 10, 3], [5, 12, 13]]
scoops_sold = 0

for location in sales_data:
  for element in location:
    scoops_sold += element
print(scoops_sold)
```

This gives me 96 as the result

What I essentially want to accomplish is to return the sum of each sublist but I am not sure I might be able to do that. I thought about using slicing but that was not effective

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve it using `sum()`:

```
print(list(map(sum, sales_data)))
```

If you insist on loops:

```
sums = []
for location in sales_data:
  sold = 0
  for element in location:
    sold += element
  sums.append(sold)
print(sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[sum(sub_list) for sub_list in sales_data]
# [51, 15, 30]
```

However, the question is a bit confusing because you are setting `scoops_sold` to 0, an `int`, when the result you describe is a `list` of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the `sum` of all subsets, you might want to use a `list` to store each subsets' sum, and by using the `built-in` python function `sum`, you just need to use one loop:

```python
    scoops_sold = []
    for sale_data in sales_data:
        salscoops_solds_sum.append(sum(sale_data))
```

The same result can be achieved in one line by using [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```python
scoops_sold = [sum(sale_data) for sale_data in sales_data]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sales_data = [[12, 17, 22], [2, 10, 3], [5, 12, 13]]
scoops_sold = 0

for location in sales_data:
  print(location)
  for element in location:
    scoops_sold += element

print(scoops_sold)
```

Comment: But this returns nothing. It is just a copy of OP's code, with an extra print.

Comment: i think he was stuck in codecademy question . That is why i posted my answer so he will no longer be stuck.(sorry if i made some english errors i am not good on it but i always try  )